# How to make legends have colours that correspond to data points using python's plotly?

Tags: python, colors, plotly, legend

I'm following the plotly [documentation](https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/color-scales/) for colouring a scatter graph. Here is my code:

I first create a fake data frame with the same shape as what I'm working with

```
import pandas
import colorlover as cl
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy
data = numpy.random.normal(0, 1, 3*6*11*2)
data = data.reshape(((3*6*11), 2))
data = pandas.DataFrame(data)
sub_experiments = ['Subexperiment_{}'.format(i) for i in [1, 2, 3]]
repeats = ['Repeat_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 7)]
time = ['{}h'.format(i) for i in range(11)]

array = [sub_experiments, repeats, time]
idx = pandas.MultiIndex.from_product(array, names=['SubExperiment', 'Repeats', 'Time'])
data.index = idx
```

Now my I want to create a scatter graph with plotly:

```
scatters = []
for label, df in data.groupby(level=[0, 1]):
    scales = cl.scales[str(df.shape[0])]
    colour = scales['qual']['Paired']
    d = go.Scatter(
        x=df[0],
        y=df[1],
        mode='markers',
        name=reduce(lambda x, y: '{}_{}'.format(x, y), label),
        marker=go.Marker(color=colour, line=go.Line(color='black')),
    )
    scatters.append(d)
```

And looks like this:

[image]

Note that since I've made up data for this example and I'm actually doing principle component analysis, the plot in the above screenshot shows clusters while the example code will not.

The problem here is that `plotly` has not coloured the legend like the points.

How can I colour the legend in the same way as the points ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array with colours for each trace, i.e. the each traces has several different colors, picking one in the legend doesn't really make sense (try removing the `color=colour` to see the effect).

Based on your code I am not sure what you are expecting to see, i.e. whether the color should be based on the label, i.e subexperiment+repeat or time (as defined in the code).

In the first case, you could just pick one color for each trace. In the latter case, plotting the time and assigning one color to each time makes more sense in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, this was my problem. I didn't quite grasp what I was doing with `color=colour`. Now that I get this I've been able to fix my code. Thanks